# html input type file show all files in file dialog popup

Tags: html

I have an input that only accepts xls, xlsx and csv files but for some reason on windows the file picker dialog only displays xls files by default. Is there a way to make it show "all files" by default in the filter dropdown?

Here's how my input looks like

```html
<input type="file" name="file" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,text/csv" onChange={changeHandler} ref={fileInputRef} />
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by  `but for some reason`? the reason is unexpected?

Comment: Please clarify what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correct you are expecting it to accept only `.xls`, `.xlsx` and `.csv`, you need this:

```html
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

**Valid Accept Types:**

For **CSV** files (**.csv**), use:

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" />
```

For **Excel** Files 97-2003 (**.xls**), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

For **Excel** Files 2007+ (**.xlsx**), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

Comment: I have the accept in there already. What I'm talking about is the filter at the bottom right part of the Windows system file dialog, where it has "xls" preselected. I'd like it to display all files by default so users can pick between all accepted formats.

Comment: Users can only view/select those files of the type you mention inside `accept`. In case you want to display all files in picker, you need to keep `accept="*"` so that it accepts all files.